# Excluding a search from txt file in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file Unregister.bat

```
    set UNREG="%~1"
    SET COMUnReg="%~dp0_tools_\bin\regasm.exe" /u
    SET FILES="%~dp0COMRegisteredNames.txt"

    FOR /F "delims= " %%a IN ('type %FILES%') DO (
    FOR /R "%UNREG%" %%f IN (*%%a*) DO (
        Echo UnRegistering %%f
        %COMUnReg% %%f
    )
)
```

the txt file contains file names to be unregistered .

```
File1.dll
File2.dll
```

I give a folder as input where all dll files are located as well as some different files . Now I want only dll files to be taken to unregister, not any other with same name like.

```
File2.dll.manifest
```

I want to take File2.dll search to unregister ,but not File2.dll.manifest search to unregister, any idea how to do this ?

Comment: why then do you use `*%%a*` instead of `"%%a"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```bat
@echo off
SET COMUnReg="%~dp0_tools_\bin\regasm.exe" /u
SET FILES="%~dp0COMRegisteredNames.txt"

FOR /F "delims= " %%f IN ('Type %FILES%') DO (
    If /I "%%~xf" EQU ".DLL" (
        Echo UnRegistering "%%f"
        %COMUnReg% "%%f"
    )

)
pause>nul & exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Stefan's comment, you can just change `*%%a*` with `"*%%a"` to unregister `Something.dll` but not `Something.dll*`.